# Broken pkg install - howto fix?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Below see attempt to remove pkg; synaptic is unhelpful and I don't know enough to go further...any way to FORCE removal of a pkg when necessary?

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove libwayland-dev
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libwayland-dev:
 libgtk-3-dev depends on libwayland-dev (>= 1.2.0).
dpkg: error processing package libwayland-dev (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libwayland-dev
```

Identified pkg dependencies, but can't get removed/fixed...

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove libgtk-3-dev libcinnamon-desktop-dev libcinnamon-control-center-dev
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `libwayland-dev' contains empty filename
```

Any help would be appreciated; trying to remove 'libwayland-dev' but file apparently has installation errors (empty filename)?

Answer (score 0):

To remove broken packages run `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name`

Afterwards run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: No need for a reboot.

Comment: @A.B. you're everywhere :P